# django-mptt OperationalError no such column

Tags: django

I've installed django-mptt and django-mptt-admin.

When trying to add a item via admin i get:
OperationalError at /admin/item/item/add/
Exception Value:
no such column: item_item.lft

I belive this has to do with the tables is not created.

But I added both mptt and mptt-admin in installed_apps in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'mptt',
    'django_mptt_admin',
```

I have also run the migrations in the terminal.

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>
python manage.py migrate
```

I have also tried

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

and get this

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: django_mptt_admin, messages, mptt, staticfiles
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, item, sessions
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

Now I'm out of ideas to solve this

By request, my model that use the MPTT

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class Item(MPTTModel):
    item_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    item_parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)
    dateAdded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    userAdded = models.ForeignKey(User)

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['item_title']
        parent_attr = 'item_parent'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_title
```

Comment: Can you list the model code?

Comment: why --run-syncdb?

Comment: @manassehkatz The model is over 1000 rows. I think maybe it's better if you take a look inside the model from their github
https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt

Comment: @sumpen I don't mean django-mptt's code. I mean YOUR model - it should be something like `class Item(MPTTModel)`. Not the data, just the structure/class.

Comment: @manassehkatz Haha. Look at me- see how stupid I am. ;-)
I have updated the OP with my model that use mpttmodel.

Comment: For info: I don't know why, but when I remove
dateAdded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    userAdded = models.ForeignKey(User)
It works in grid view. Not tree view.